# I am trying to add a recipe to my new meta-layer, but facing ERROR NOTHING FOUND

Tags: linux, build, yocto, bitbake, recipe

I want to create a recipe for this https://github.com/kuscsik/streamfs in my new layer (meta-example) and include it to image.

My layer is added in bblayers.conf :

```
~/rdk/build-raspberrypi-rdk-hybrid$ bitbake-layers show-layers

**layer                 path                                      priority**

**meta-example          /home/xyz/rdk/build-raspberrypi-rdk-hybrid/meta-example  6**
```

This is my path to layer.conf and content in layer.conf:

```
~/rdk/build-raspberrypi-rdk-hybrid/meta-example/conf$ vi layer.conf

#We have a conf and classes directory, add to BBPATH

BBPATH .=":${LAYERDIR}"

#We have recipes-* directories, add to BBFILES

BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb\
    ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbapend"

BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "example"

BBFILE_PATTERN_example = "^${LAYERDIR}/"

BBFILE_PRIORITY_example = "6"
```

Then i have created a directory(example) inside meta-example which contains streamfs_git.bb with contents as shown below:

```
~/rdk/build-raspberrypi-rdk-hybrid/meta-example/example$ vi streamfs_git.bb

DESCRIPTION = "First recipe"

HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/kuscsik/streamfs"

LICENSE = "LGPL-2.1"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=fc178bcd425090939a8b634d1d6a9594"

inherit cmake pkgconfig

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/kuscsik/streamfs"

SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
```

Then i run this command :~/rdk/build-raspberrypi-rdk-hybrid/meta-example/example$ bitbake streamfs_git

It shows me this error

**WARNING: No bb files matched BBFILE_PATTERN_example '^/home/xyz/rdk/build-raspberrypi-rdk-hybrid/meta-example/'**

****ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'streamfs_git'**

I have even tried bitbake streamfs_git.bb and bitbake streamfs also, all are giving same error.

How can I fix the error? Do I have to add something in my layer.conf or .bb file or is there an error in any of my steps?

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed two potential errors right away within your BBFILES declaration. You have

```
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-//.bb
${LAYERDIR}/recipes-//.bbapend"
```

The first issue being that BBFILES is looking for any recipes in AND ONLY in a directory called 'recipes-'. I'm assuming (I could be wrong) that your recipes directory isn't called 'recipes-'. To ensure any recipes within a folder are getting parsed, make sure your bbfiles properly points to the directory that it resides in. In this case, perhaps change 'recipes-' to 'recipes-[directory-name]', although you can also use wildcards here, so something like 'recipes-*' would work as well, giving you the ability to parse any recipes within any directory named 'recipes-[anything]'.

Additionally, you seem to have an extraneous '/' in that same line, and no declaration of your recipe name. It's generally good practice in yocto keep your recipes in a subfolder of a recipes-* directory, though it's only for organizational reasons. You're also only pointing to a recipes named '.bb'. You should have either a wildcard, or the exact recipe name here. Also, don't forget to separate your multilined variables with a \ at the end of each line. It should look something like:

```
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \
```

Moving to the second line, it's the same issues with lack of wildcards/direct definitions, although there also seems to be a typo in 'bbapend', which is just in spelling, should be 'bbappend'.

Ultimately, you should end up with something like this

```
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \
${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"
```

There may be more issues, though work on this stuff for now, and I'll help out more if this doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: i have used this exactly as you have said:
BBFILES += "${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \
${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend"

but during copying and pasting in stack overflow those stars were not printed.

Again in this comment maybe those 3*'s are not printed but they r there in the code for sure.

Comment: What you just pasted is not exactly what I gave you. Also, you don't need to copy and paste, you can just type it out. I actually normally recommend against direct copy and pasting as it somewhat takes away from the learning experience.